# Memory leak with jquery dialog e jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, memory-leaks, jqgrid, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following function that create a jQuery Dialog and setup a jqGrid on it.
My code runs within IE 8.

Every time I open the dialog I notice an increase of memory of the browser which is around 30 MB. 
When I close the dialog this memory is not freed.

Where do this code leaks?

```
function ShowData() {
    var gridID = "my_detail_grid";
    var pagerID = gridID + "_pager";
    var markup = $('<div style="display: none;">' +
                    '<input type="hidden" id="pclist_ownerID" name="pclist_ownerID" />' +
                    '<table id="' + gridID + '"></table>' +
                    '<div id="' + pagerID + '"></div>' +
                   '</div>');
    var owner = $('#pclist_ownerID', markup);
    markup.dialog({
        autoOpen: false, modal: true, stack: true, resizable: false, position: 'center',
        width: 860, height: 400,
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(gridID).jqGrid('GridUnload');
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'MyWebService.asmx/GetAdditionalData',
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ objectID: objectID }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var title = titlePrefix + data.d.objectname + " - " + data.d.period;
            markup.dialog("option", "title", title);
            owner.val(data.d.workgroupid);
        }
    });
    markup.dialog('open');
    var grid = $('#' + gridID);
    grid.jqGrid({
        url: 'MyWebService.asmx/MyMethod',
        colNames: [
            'Field1',
            'Field2',
            'Field3'
        ],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Field1', index: 'Field1', width: 120, sortable: false, align: 'left', search: true, template: colTextTemplate, searchrules: { required: false } },
            { name: 'Field2', index: 'Field2', width: 170, sortable: false, align: 'left', search: true, template: colTextTemplate, searchrules: { required: false} },
            { name: 'Field3', index: 'Field3', width: 170, sortable: false, align: 'left', search: true, template: colTextTemplate, searchrules: { required: false} }
        ],
        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
            if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },
        jsonReader: {
            id: "MyRecordID"
        },
        footerrow: false,
        userDataOnFooter: true,
        sortname: 'MyRecordID',
        sortorder: "asc",
        pager: $('#' + pagerID),
        rownumbers: true,
        gridComplete: function () {
            //this method just enable or disable the add/edit/delete based on conditions 
            reconfigPermissions();
        },
        gridview: true,
        autowidth: false,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        width: 830,
        height: 264
    })
    .jqGrid('navGrid', '#' + pagerID,
        {
            add: true, addtitle: 'Add Record',
            edit: true, edittitle: 'Edit Record',
            del: true, deltitle: 'Delete Record',
            refresh: false,
            search: false,  //searchtitle: 'Advanced search filters',
            addfunc: function () {
                // code for add
            },
            editfunc: function () {
               // code for edit
            }
        },
        { /*default settings for edit*/ },
        { /*default settings for add*/ },
        {
            /* settings for delete*/
            // define settings for Delete 
            mtype: "post", reloadAfterSubmit: true,
            url: 'MyWebService.asmx/Delete',
            resize: false,
            serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
                return JSON.stringify({ recordID: postdata.id });
            },
            afterSubmit: function (data, postdata) {
            }
        },
        {},
        {}
    )
    .jqGrid('navSeparatorAdd', '#' + pagerID, {})
    .jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#' + pagerID, {
        caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-search", position: "last", title: "Advanced search filters",
        onClickButton: function () {
            grid.searchGrid({
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'bw', 'cn'],
                closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true, recreateFilter: true
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping!

**EDIT**: No advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sounds strange. jqGrid works not clean with memory. Nevertheless I don't think that increasing memory in 30 MB on after every opening of dialog could be explained by jqGrid only. The grid which you use don't contains `rowNum`. So the default value 20 (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)) will be used. You don't use `loadonce: true` option, so `'MyWebService.asmx/MyMethod'` used as the URL in the grid should returns about 20*4 cell values (3 columns + id column). Such response and all DOM structures created by jqGrid can't take 30 MB memory.

So I suppose that the reason of the problem could be other as jqGrid. You can use Fiddler, Developer Tools of IE or Chrome to trace HTTP traffic. I recommend you to verify responses from `'MyWebService.asmx/MyMethod'` and from `'MyWebService.asmx/GetAdditionalData'`. It can be that some response contains too much data. Reducing of data will not really solve the problem, but 30 KB of memory leaks will be not so important as leaks of the size 30 MB. By the way you can use `userData` and refresh the title of the dialog (make the same set of dialog option "title") inside of `loadComplete`. In the way you would save synchronous (`async: false` ???) Ajax call.

Additionally I would recommend you to change (temporary, only for the test) the `datatype` option from `"json"` to `"local"`. No request to the URL `'MyWebService.asmx/MyMethod'` will be done in the case and you could verify whether call of the method and filling the grid data are responsible for 30 MB which is your main problem.

You would recommend you to use `deepempty: true` option of jqGrid additionally.

If all your test will show that jqGrid is do responsible for memory leaks then you will have to replace `$(gridID).jqGrid('GridUnload');` call to recursive cleaning of all DOM structures (cells and rows) created by jqGrid. I hope that it will be not needed.

Comment: Well, for simplicity I didn't reported all the columns. Actually the grid has 11 Columns + ID column. 10 of those columns are string data and the last one is a float value. There are maximum 15 records returned. However I think that the code does not leak only on jqGrid but also in the dialog creation part. Could you please suggest an alternative to `$(gridID).jqGrid('GridUnload');`?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `deepempty` parameter!

Comment: @Lorenzo: I suggest that you try with `datatype: "local"` first to verify that 30 MB memory leaks come really from jqGrid. One can invest a lot of time in searching of the problem where there are no problem at all. So first of all one should verify that jqGrid is the origin of 30 MB memory leaks.

Comment: @Lorenzo: Do you have found the reason of the problem with 30 MB memory leaks? What was the reason?

Comment: As you guessed, it wasn't everyhting a fault of jqGrid. However the usage of deepemty parameter worked very well. Also I have changed a little bit the code of the dialog by adding it to the page markup and not leaving it just in memory.